# Pages stuck after force-quit in paused state

Tags: pages, performance, force-quit

Today my application memory ran out and a prompt asked me to quit applications I did not require. I (force-)quit all my apps (there was no option to quit because the applications were 'paused'.

While I was using Pages, I was working on a document ("Untitled 5") that I had created from scratch and did not yet save. I suspect that force-quitting in the paused state of Pages confused it (IIRC Pages will save documents in the background so that if force-quit they will not be lost) and when trying to do anything with the document, Pages will freeze.

(I suspect this doesn't matter, but I'm using an Early 2015 MacBook Pro, running 10.12.1 macOS Sierra, Pages version v6.0 (3507) )

---

**Update**:
I found out that the document was saved in iCloud Drive (saw the upload indicator after force-quitting Pages) and was able to retrieve it.

However, now Pages only opens (without crashing, that is), when launching it from the Dock. After opening Pages with any document, it functions fine (can close the document I used, move, save etc.) and Pages quits properly.

---

<s>what happened earlier, before I found the document:</s>

I have tried:

1. Saving the document
2. Closing the document
3. Moving the document (yea, I know)
4. Typing words into the document works

Will update what I have tried as time goes on. I think that anything with the (probably glitched) document will freeze Pages, while anything else will not. For example, I tried making a new document and it worked fine. It doesn't matter whether I lose the document or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Still having this issue? Have you tried deleting Pages and installing it again from the Mac App Store?

Comment: @owlswipe yeah it's been resolved but for some reason I can't remember what I did... I had to try quite a lot of stuff. Initially I logged in and out of iCloud, then reinstalled Pages, and then deleted my iCloud Drive pages files because I think they were causing an issue. Not sure which one it is though.

Comment: Alright, glad it's fixed.